# How to use reCaptcha2 solving Services in Selenium python : Python Auto Captcha solver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, recaptcha, captcha, 2captcha

I am trying to automate a website and it's displaying captcha at some point I just want to know how I can add Auto Recaptcha solving services in my code so the execution of the code does not stop. I have tried Anti-captcha but it's not working and they don't have proper instruction on how I can use their service.

https://anticaptcha.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/API/pages/196635/Documentation+in+English
This is an anti-captcha documentation page but I am not getting what I have to do to use it in python.

Is there any way I can bypass reCaptcha using any paid service?

Comment: might be helpful: https://anti-captcha.com/mainpage

Answer (score 1):

I've used 2captcha before for automating captcha solving. So that would be my first go to. They have easy to read documentation and getting it setup with selenium isnt to challenging. https://2captcha.com/api_examples